# Can I increase the height of the rendered element using html2canvas within the onclone function?

Tags: html, reactjs, html2canvas

I'm using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to render a few client-side PNGs for users to download content. It is working well, but we recently got an ask to add a static footer and a dynamic header to each PNG that a user downloads.

Since the footer is static, I can add a fixed height to the `ref` element `height: ref.offsetHeight + CONSTANT_HEIGHT`, so that we always have enough space available once we add the footer inside the `onclone` function, but with the header the height is always different, so I'm wondering if there is a way to hold off assigning the height to the `html2canvas` function until after `onclone` has completed?

```
export const getPng = async (
  ref: HTMLElement,
): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement> => html2canvas(ref, {
  scrollY: -window.scrollY,
  height: ref.offsetHeight, // starts at 922px, but after clone is much higher
  onclone: (doc: Document) => {
    const elem = doc.getElementById(ref.id) as HTMLElement;

    // Create a <div/> to hold the contents of our React building blocks
    const rootEl = doc.createElement('div');
    doc.body.appendChild(rootEl);
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Footer/>,
      rootEl,
    );

    // Grab the footer elements from our React component
    const footer = doc.getElementById(EXPORT_FOOTER_ID) as HTMLElement;

    // Insert the HTML of the <Footer/> elements into our existing element
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'beforeend',
      footer.outerHTML,
    );

    console.log(`elem height ${elem.offsetHeight}`); // is now 1040px, but prints out at 1844px (window.devicePixelRatio = 2)
  },
});
```